# NameError: name 'chat_id' is not defined

Tags: python

у меня есть код:

```
def start(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    bot.send_message(chat_id, 'памагити пж' ,reply_markup = menu)
    return(chat_id)

def message():
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "123")
```

и после этого выдаёт ошибку:

```
    message()
NameError: name 'chat_id' is not defined
```

Comment: Ну да, у вас внутри функции `message` и в самом деле не существует никакого `chat_id`. Это всё, что тут можно сказать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это телеграммный бот, то функция, обрабатывающая сообщение, должна быть обёрнута в специальный декоратор. А вторая функция в вашем коде - вообще что-то ненужное и нежизнеспособное, её нужно просто убрать.

То есть ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    bot.send_message(chat_id, 'памагити пж')
    return(chat_id)
```

Но не уверен, что именно таким должен быть код, сам я под телеграмм не пишу.
Возможно, вам будет полезна эта статья: https://habr.com/ru/post/462905/